# How to read environment variable "ProgramFiles(x86)" in CMake

Tags: cmake

How can I read the value of the ProgramFiles(x86) environment variable using CMake's $ENV variable?

```
# work fine
message( "$ENV{ProgramW6432}" )
message( "$ENV{ProgramFiles}" )
# error parsing (
message( "$ENV{ProgramFile(x86)}" )
```

The brackets are causing CMake's parser to choke.

TIA

Comment: Have you tried `$ENV{ProgramFiles\(x86\)}`?

Comment: Can you please give some details what you want to do with the result? It's just a guess, but I think you don't really need it. E.g. the `find_...()` commands do automatically prefix those paths (see [`WindowsPaths.cmake`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/Platform/WindowsPaths.cmake) and [`CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROGRAM_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROGRAM_PATH.html)).

Comment: @Florian it's common to use `$ENV{ProgramFiles}` to compose a known default install path for a tool in the `PATHS` argument to `find_program` and similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a [know issue](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/CMP0053-Unable-to-refer-to-ENV-PROGRAMFILES-X86-td7588994.html).

Try escaping the parentheses:

```
message("$ENV{ProgramFiles\(x86\)}")
```

Or use a temporary variable:

```
set(_pf_x86 "ProgramFiles(x86)")
message("$ENV{${_pf_x86 }}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape the parentheses with backslashes, i.e.:

```
message( "$ENV{ProgramFiles\(x86\)}" )
```